# CSS - don't animate value on elements with certain class?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm working with React js and I have created a nav where lines animate from 0% to 100% under items on hover and the last item that was clicked gets assigned the `.current` class. The item with class `.current` should not animate but should maintain the line at 100% width. I had this working previously but I added CSS that moves the text in `<li>`'s on hover and it broke.

Snippet:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "sequel-sans-roman", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 4rem 0;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navIcon {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2.4em;
  /* coordinates w height of line away from link, MUST BE = */
}

.snip1168 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.snip1168 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.snip1168 li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  background: ppink;
}

.snip1168 li {
  padding: 2.4em 0 0.5em;
  /* height of line away from link */
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: pink;
  display: inline-block;
}

.snip1168 li:before,
.snip1168 li:after {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.snip1168 li:before {
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
}

.snip1168 li:hover:before,
.snip1168 .current a:before {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.snip1168 li:hover:after,
.snip1168 .current li:after {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.mainText {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.snip1168 li a {
  transition: transform ease 400ms;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
}

.snip1168 li:hover a {
  transition: transform ease 400ms;
  transform: translate(0, -10px);
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <main class='main'>
    <div class='nav'>
      <div class='navIcon'>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/40" height={40} width={40} />
      </div>
      <ul class='snip1168'>
        <li class='current'><a href="#" data-hover="Work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-hover="Recs">Recs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-hover="Say Hi">Say Hi</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

I have tried doing something like this but it has no effect:

```
.snip1168 .current a {
  width: 100%;
}
```

How can I keep the lines at 100% width on `.current` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want the line that animates to stay visible aka 100% width when the .current is applied.

I believe Im seeing couple of mistakes especially with your selectors but to prevent breaking your existing code, adding this should fix it.

```
ul li.current::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the above code, you have used class="current" to show the clicked nav item, however, a good approach is to use id="current" instead (because there always will be a single item which is active/clicked/current) and add a new CSS rule like below.

```
li#current::before{
width:100% !important;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "sequel-sans-roman", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 4rem 0;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navIcon {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2.4em;
  /* coordinates w height of line away from link, MUST BE = */
}

.snip1168 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.snip1168 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.snip1168 li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  background: ppink;
}

.snip1168 li {
  padding: 2.4em 0 0.5em;
  /* height of line away from link */
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: pink;
  display: inline-block;
}

.snip1168 li:before,
.snip1168 li:after {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.snip1168 li:before {
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
}


.snip1168 li:hover:before,
.snip1168 .current a:before {
  opacity: 1; /*not needed*/
  width: 100%;
}

/*Added Code*/

li#current::before{
  width:100% !important;
}

.snip1168 li:hover:after,
.snip1168 .current li:after {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.mainText {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.snip1168 li a {
  transition: transform ease 400ms;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <main class='main'>
    <div class='nav'>
      <div class='navIcon'>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/40" height={40} width={40} />
      </div>
      <ul class='snip1168'>
        <li id='current'><a href="#" data-hover="Work">Work</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#" data-hover="Recs">Recs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-hover="Say Hi">Say Hi</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Working example : [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anubhavmunjaal/pen/MWVgEYe?editors=1100)